Troubleshooting Yubikey for interacting with Git repositories using SSH
I have successfully created SSH resident keys in my Yubikey and used it successfully to interact with GitHub repositories from a work / corporate laptop in the past.
I recently needed to change my laptop at work and found that interacting with GitHub no longer works from this laptop.
I have successfully been able to download the public key and private key stubs from the Yubikey on the new laptop and given permissions to my regular user account. I have also configured SSH to use that private key against github.com.
winget install Microsoft.OpenSSH.Beta
ssh-keygen -K
cacls id_ed25519_sk_rk_github.com_12345     /e /p DOMAIN/username:f
cacls id_ed25519_sk_rk_github.com_12345.pub /e /p DOMAIN/username:f
echo "Host github.com`r`n`tIdentityFile C:\Users\username\.ssh\id_ed25519_sk_rk_github.com_12345" >>~/.ssh/config

I have enabled verbose logging in SSH and run the following commands:
$Env:GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"
git clone git@github.com:username/repository.git
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: c:\\Users\\username\\.ssh\\id_ed25519_sk_rk_github.com_12345 ED25519-SK SHA256:KEYKEYKEY explicit authenticator
debug1: Server accepts key: c:\\Users\\username\\.ssh\\id_ed25519_sk_rk_github.com_12345 ED25519-SK SHA256:KEYKEYKEY explicit authenticator
Enter PIN for ED25519-SK key c:\Users\username\.ssh\id_ed25519_sk_rk_github.com_12345:
Confirm user presence for key ED25519-SK SHA256:KEYKEYKEY
debug1: start_helper: starting /usr/lib/ssh/ssh-sk-helper
debug1: process_sign: ready to sign with key ED25519-SK, provider internal: msg len 194, compat 0x0
debug1: sshsk_sign: provider "internal", key ED25519-SK, flags 0x25 with-pin
debug1: sk_probe: 0 device(s) detected
debug1: ssh_sk_sign: failed to find sk
debug1: sshsk_sign: sk_sign failed with code -4
debug1: ssh-sk-helper: Signing failed: device not found
debug1: main: reply len 8
debug1: client_converse: helper returned error -60
debug1: identity_sign: sshkey_sign: device not found
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519-SK "c:\\Users\\username\\.ssh\\id_ed25519_sk_rk_github.com_12345": device not found
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Is there a way to troubleshoot or workaround this issue ?
